# Enable mysqlnd using php_flag in htaccess

Tags: php

any knows how i can enable mysqlnd using php_flag in .htaccess ¿?

I use Hostinger.es free hosting and i cant use $statement->get_result().

Thankz a lot.

PD: Now i can try this:

> php_flag mysqlnd_ms 1

but nothing happens.

Comment: Free hosting almost certainly means shared hosting, which almost certainly means you can't do this yourself. Ask your host, and be prepared for a "huh?" answer.

Comment: You need VPS for this

Comment: @Rafael Possibly. Some shared hosts may be willing to provide it, but as duskwuff points out, who needs MySQL load balancing on shared hosting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't.

`mysqlnd_ms` is an extension, not a configuration option. Extensions cannot be loaded from `.htaccess` files.

(`mysqlnd_ms` is **not** something you need here. It is an extension used for interfacing with load-balanced MySQL clusters, which are almost certainly not present in a shared hosting environment.)

More generally, the `mysqlnd` driver (which is not the same as `mysqlnd_ms`!) must be enabled when PHP is compiled. It cannot be enabled by users later on.

Find a better hosting provider. Free hosts are generally awful.

Comment: "mysqlnd_ms is not something you need here." Probably the most important and relevant part. +1!

Comment: i have this message: Fatal error: Call to undefined method mysqli_stmt::get_result() in /home/u516401807/public_html/... on line 39
 
In conection class i have this script:

if (function_exists('mysqli_fetch_all')) {
    echo 'mysqlnd enabled!';
}

I guess not loaded the library